# Mini version of JPA entity classes and relating them

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, specifications

I am looking for creating a smaller version of an entity class.

I have Patient table and Diabetic Patient table and medicines table.. And they are all huge master tables.

I would like to create mini versions and use them for listing.. like Patient Mini, Diabetic Patient mini and medicines mini.

Is that possible in JPA with Hibernate. I can not do anything directly on Master entities since they are used by different other teams and i have a limitation of using the entire entities rather than individual fields in it.. So is there a way to create such mini version of the entity classes. Please advice.

Comment: Just use a DTO and write a JPQL that fills the DTO. You don't need an additional entity for that.

Comment: i am using JPA specifications for these entities such as  diabeticpatientsinpresentfacilityspecifcation and pediatriccdiabeticpatientsspecification etc using specification similarly for patients. so when i use specifications its firing lots of queries in this case for larger set of existing data. hence i would like to use mini versions for these entities and then use them inside specification. So that minimum amount of queries are fired.

Comment: Again you don't need the mini. The additional queries come from the fact you are using full entities and not projections. Due to the full entities (and not projections) it is full fulling all the mappings and retrieves all columns. If you use a `findAll` with a projection (a dto) it doesn't fire all those queries.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some DTOs and use `select new` to query and fill the DTOs out of the box. The DTOs classes must provide a constructor that takes all the attributes that you need to be fetched by the result set of the query.

example:

```
List<PatientDTO> PatientDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("select new your.package.structure.dto.PatientDTO(p.id, p.name, p.medicines) from Patient p ", PatientDTO.class).getResultList();
```

if you want to know more about how map a projection query to a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with JPA and Hibernate :
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Please note that i am using JPA specifications and ANDing them and using findall method to get final result. So populating Dto this way is not helping me. Is there way to make mini entitity like patientmini and use them inside my specification for patient.

Comment: @Joys using “Constructor Expressions in the SELECT Clause (SELECT NEW)” is part of the JPA specification (JSR-338) point 4.8.2 , pages 199-200.  

But if you going to create a new system/app, there is no problem with mapping those “mini entities” with just  the attributes/columns that you need to be fetched.

Comment: Yes, you can map two or more entities to the same database table.

here you can find more info ->

https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-map-multiple-entities-same-table/